# How to scrape a span class without Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, python-3.x

I've looked already for quite a while for a solution online, but I can't find any, where I don't have to install beautiful soup. I'm restricted to what I can install on my laptop, so, unfortunately, this is not an option.

The question is probably easy for the experts, but I, as a beginner, struggle.

I'm using
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08)
IPython 7.19.0

I want to get the number 158 from the span element:

```html
<div class="no-p">
  <em class"red" style="font-size: 20px;">
    <span>158</span>
  </em>
</div> == $0
```

I show you know what I have done in Jupyter so far, but it doesn't work :(

```html
url_base = 'https://www.a-hotel.com/saudi-arabia/8411-makkah/?unknown_date=1&person_count=2&room_count=1'
driver.get(url_base)
html = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
num_hotel = html.xpath('//div[@class="no-p"]/span/text()')
print(num_hotel)
```

If you can help me, that would be much appreciated. Thanks.
Urs

Comment: If this is really the data, then it should read `class*=*"red"` instead of `class"red"`. But the parser should already complain about this.

Comment: `span` is inside `em`, so the XPath should be explicit `//div/em/span` or maybe `//div//span`.

Comment: Please couldmyou show your import statements ? Because i guessed etree refers to xml.etree, but on my machine xml.etree has no submodule HTML !

Comment: Thank you for your replies. This is the real data and I can't change it, as this is from a webpage I try to scrape. The 2nd answer helped me, as I didn't realise I missed em - so I will change the path and run my script again. Thank you.